# How can I remove ads from multiple views using In-App purchase in Swift (Already works in 1 view)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase, iad

I'm making my first game app and I'm making an In-App Purchase now which allows you to remove the ads from the app. Everything works well, but after the purchase it only removes the ads from the 'Home Screen' and not from the 'Game Screen' and the 'Game Over Screen'. 
How can I remove the ads from ALL the screens after the purchase?

This is the code from my 'Home Screen'/ The first screen you see when you start up the app.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var outRemoveAds: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    outRemoveAds.enabled = false

// THIS IS THE CODE I USED FOR THE iAD BANNER

// Init iAd banner ======

    _adBanner = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50) )
    _adBanner?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.view.addSubview(_adBanner!)

// AND AFTER PURCHASE IT DOES THIS

func removeAds() {
        _adBanner?.removeFromSuperview()
        _bannerIsVisible = false

    }
```

But as I said, it only removes it from the current view/screen, and not from the other 2 screens.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough code to find the problem, but first of all you have to set

```
_adBanner = nil
```

after

```
_bannerIsVisible = false
```

to let garbage collector to remove that object(it can't remove it while you have strong reference to it).
And are you sure that you are using the same view for all three controllers?  Or you are creating separate controller for every view? If so, you should check ads removal in

```
viewWillAppear
```

method of every controller.

Comment: I've got 3 different controllers for 3 different views. But I tried to change the things you suggested but It's not working unfortunately.

Comment: are you calling removeAds() for all these controllers when the adds disabler was bought?

Comment: Well I copied and pasted the function removeAds() in to the other 2 controllers but I'm pretty sure I need some sort of 'if/else' method so the computer knows if the user bought the 'disable ads' or not. But I'm not sure how to do that. Could you help me with that?

Comment: in swift you can use global vars for that. So just write in beginning of any file 
`var addsRemoved = false` and set that var while your initial controller is loading. you can store it between launches in NSUserDefaults